# Spring WebFlow - One validation for two fields

Tags: java, spring-webflow, spring-validator

I'm using Spring Webflow for a multi-paged form and I have this class (for a form in a certain page):

```
public class NameForm {
   @Size(min = 1, max = 120)
   @Pattern(regexp = GlobalRegex.NAME_REGEX)
   private String firstName;

   @Size(min = 1, max = 120)
   @Pattern(regexp = GlobalRegex.NAME_REGEX)
   private String lastName;

   private int variableX;
}
```

And a view with this model:

```
<view-state id="form" model="NameForm">
   <transition on="next" to="nextPage" validate="true">

   ...
</view-state
```

In some cases, the constraints are as indicated in the above `NameForm` (names are between 1 and 120 characters) but in other cases, which depends on the value of `variableX`, I want the sum of the lengths of `firstName` and `lastName` to be between 1 and 65 characters.

How could I do this? I heard I could build a validator programmatically, but I don't know how I could do this type of restrictions that I need.

Thank you for your help. If you need any other information, please do ask.

Answer (score 1):

After much research, I found out that the best way to do this would be to create a **class-level constraint**.

I found more information here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#section-class-level-constraints